# When and Whom are adverb, pronoun, or conjunction?

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammaticality-in-context

In the following sentence, what are the "when" and "whom" grammatical roles? And what are the meanings of them?

> The texts to classical Greek plays were written down soon after the
>   performance and possibly even before, though it is not always clear
>   **when** or by **whom**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the case of ellipsis

> The texts to classical Greek plays were written down soon after the performance and possibly even before, though it is not always clear when(they were written down) or by whom(they were written down).

When is used as adverb and whom as pronoun in this context. And the bracketed part is [ellipted](https://www.yourdictionary.com/ellipt).

Comment: Yes, ellipsis, but  "whom" is a pronoun not a conjunction. If the ellipted text were filled out, "whom" would be complement of the preposition "by". "When" is an adverb, not a conjunction. "When" and "whom", though elliptical, are subordinate interrogatives (embedded questions).